# Masonry - carregá-lo novamente após aplicação de filtros no resultado

Tags: javascript

Seguinte tenho uma página aonde aplico o plugin `masonry.js` nessa página eu tenho um filtro de conteúdo, o problema é o seguinte quando abro a pagina esta tudo ok tenho duas colunas de card com um espaçamento `x` entre elas, porem após aplicação do filtro ele limpa todo os elementos da tela e me retorna somente os elementos filtrados e nesse procedimento o masonry deixa de funcionar fazendo que o espaçamento `x` entre as colunas diminua ouuuu até mesmo fazendo com que os cards fique um em baixo do outro em somente uma coluna. Não estou conseguindo fazer com que o masonry seja iniciado novamente após o filtro.

O código é o seguinte:

```js
var refreshFeed = function(month, studentId, materialName, programId, page) {
    console.log(materialName);
    clearFeed();

    var tempFeed = feed.sort(predicatBy("build_at"));

    var numWorks = 6;

    var filteredFeed = [];

    $.each(tempFeed, function( index, value ) {

      var build_at = formatDatetime(value.build_at);

      if ((month == 0 ) || (month == build_at[1])) {
        if ((programId == 0 ) || programId == value.program_id){
          if ((materialName == "") || materialName == value.material.name) {
            if ((studentId == 0)) {
              filteredFeed.push(value);
            }else {
              $.each(value.work_students, function( index, work_student ) {
                if(work_student.student != null ) {
                  if(work_student.student.id == studentId) {
                    filteredFeed.push(value);
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });

    if (page == undefined) {
      page = 0
    };
    var finalFeed = pagination(filteredFeed, numWorks, page)

    $.each(finalFeed, function( index, value ) {
      createWorkArticle(value, month, studentId);
    });


  }
```

E para chamar o masonry eu uso o código:

```js
    var $container = $('#container-masonry');
    // initialize
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
      $container.masonry({
        columnWidth: 540,
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isFitWidth: true,
        gutter: 60
      });
    });
```

A dúvida é, como faço para carregar o plugin novamente após aplicação do filtro?

Não sei se ficou claro, mas qualquer coisa tento melhorar a pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Coloca isso dentro de uma função:

```
function chamaMasonry(){

 var $container = $('#container-masonry');
    // initialize
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
      $container.masonry({
        columnWidth: 540,
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isFitWidth: true,
        gutter: 60
      });
    });

}
```

Chama essa função quando carregar a página e chama ela na função do filtro.